# Bind OneWay and OneWayToSource separately?

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to bind a TextBox `Text` field to a property `TextView` in my model with mode `OneWay`, and bind to another property `TextInput` with mode `OneWayToSource`?

ie. If I change the `TextView` property in code, the wpf control content changes. And if I type in the TextBox, the change is reflected in `TextInput`.

I agree it's not the right way to do this, but being able to do this would spare me a lot of work right now.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you need that. I can't see why could that be useful now...

Comment: You could TwoWay-bind only one property and use different backing fields for `get` and `set`. Seems a bit hacky, though...

Comment: @Pikoh: I have a model with a lot of properties, and I have to make an override mechanism, so that if a user types something in the textbox, I keep the original value somewhere, so that the user can revert back to it if needed. So I don't want to do a 2 way binding.

Comment: @wkl: woooh, nice one. It does feel very hacky, but that'll do. Thanks

Comment: Well,then use a backup object with the original data. Doing what you want seems too hacky to me

Comment: @Pikoh: it sure is hacky, it's not for an important project, and that'll save me plenty of time though.

Comment: A binding is supposed to actually bind *one* property to another. I don’t think you can split up this behavior into two view model properties. You might be able to do this with your own binding markup extension but I don’t believe that’s less work than just *fixing* your view model.

Comment: better way would be in your VM have a property where the get does your get logic and your set does your set logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to bind a TextBox Text field to a property TextView in my model with mode OneWay, and bind to another property TextInput with mode OneWayToSource?

No. You can only apply a single binding to a target property.

You could use a multi converter to convert the value of several properties into one target value though: https://blog.csainty.com/2009/12/wpf-multibinding-and.html.

Something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
            <Binding Path="TextView" />
            <Binding Path="TextInput" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

---

```
public class NameMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    private string _textView;
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //display the value of TextView
        _textView = values[0].ToString();
        return _textView;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new object[] { _textView, /* TextInput: */ value.ToString() };
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could handle the conversion logic in the setter of your source property.